# JS function works great in FF and Safari, but takes a VERY long time in IE9

Tags: javascript

Can you see any reason it would work fine in FF and Safari, but when run in IE9 it completely craps out? It takes forever and almost hangs the browser. Thanks!

This is a function that refreshes a list after a keypress. The function clears the list, and then does a linear search through the globally defined array and adds the matches back to the list.

```
function handleKeyUp()
{
    var selectObj, textObj, componentListLength;
    var i, searchPattern, numShown;

    // Set references to the form elements
    selectObj = document.form1.componentselect;
    textObj = document.form1.componentinput;

    // Remember the function list length for loop speedup
    componentListLength = componentlist.length;

    // Set the search pattern depending
    if(document.form1.componentradio[0].checked == true)
    {
        searchPattern = "^"+textObj.value;
    }
    else
    {
        searchPattern = textObj.value;
    }

    // Create a regular expression
    re = new RegExp(searchPattern,"gi");
    // Clear the options list
    selectObj.length = 0;

    // Loop through the array and re-add matching options
    numShown = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < componentListLength; i++)
    {
        if(componentlist[i].search(re) != -1)
        {
            selectObj[numShown] = new Option(componentlist[i],"");
            numShown++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you step through it in the script debugger and try to figure out what's taking so long?  Also, what's the value of componentListLength?  Are you working with some massive list?

Comment: There are roughly 6500 items in the list.

Comment: Also, it is the 'for' loop that IE has trouble with. In FF, for instance, I can step over it in the debugger very quickly. However, IE has to chug for quite a bit to step past the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that look fishy to me:

```
// Clear the options list
selectObj.length = 0;
// should be
selectObj.options.length = 0;


// Next thing, adding them back
selectObj[numShown] = new Option(componentlist[i],"");
// should be
selectObj.options[numShown] = new Option(componentlist[i],"");
```